# How to uninstall JDK 8 (8u73) on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, uninstallation

I installed the JDK 8 update 73 together with Netbeans to play around with it. The whole thing was pretty cumbersome so I decided to uninstall them both and went back to Brackets.

For Netbeans it was like a walk in the park with its already provided uninstaller packet ".sh" in the directory.

However, with JDK, there seems to be no freaking way for me to rid of this thing. I searched for anything "jdk" in Software Manager and removed everything I saw in there. I also digged into the usr/lib/jvm to manually delete any leftover folders. But, as soon as I ran the installer packet ".sh" it told me that JDK 8 update 73 was *still* already installed....

Can you guys please help me remove this completely??? Many thanks!!

PS: I'm using Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit.

Comment: Ever thought about looking in the installer script to see what it is looking to find older installations?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to find files:

sudo find /usr/ -name "*jdk*"

sudo find /opt/ -name "*jdk*"

sudo find /etc/ -name "*jdk*"

Now if that doesn't find files, try with another keyword like "java".
And if that doesn't work then the installer may be checking for defined variables like $JAVA_HOME, you can check if it's defined by doing:

echo $JAVA_HOME

if it prints a path, then it's set and you need to unset it. See the following page for a reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 0):

Go to synaptic manager or software center and remove jdk.  If it worked pls reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think JDK placed in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.xxx` or something like there.

It's better to install separately JDK and Netbeans.
My favourite way to install JDK in Mint (I'm using Linux Mint 17.3) [described here.](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you can remove it from:

```
Control Panel of Windows > Add/Remove Programs > Choose Java SDK
```

you want to remove